# raspi SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data. For automated RC car

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I've been following "Beginning Robotics with Raspberry Pi and Arduino" book and have run into a problem with the code. I am pretty new to programming and am using this book to familiarize myself with the Pi and Arduino and Python as well. The book is somewhat vague and doesn't offer remedies for problems.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Danberry/Roject/pi_roamer_01.py", line 80, in <module>
    val = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
  File "/home/Danberry/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 501, in read
    'device reports readiness to read but returned no data '
SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

I have confirmed that everything is hooked up properly and works individually. The problem is now getting the raspberry pi to read it.

```
import serial
import time
import random

from Adafruit_MotorHAT import Adafruit_MotorHAT as amhat
from Adafruit_MotorHAT import Adafruit_DCMotor as adamo

# create motor objects
motHAT = amhat(addr=0x60)
mot1 = motHAT.getMotor(1)
mot2 = motHAT.getMotor(2)
mot3 = motHAT.getMotor(3)
mot4 = motHAT.getMotor(4)

# open serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)

# create variables
# sensors
distMid = 0.0
distLeft = 0.0
distRight = 0.0

# motor multipliers
m1Mult = 1.0
m2Mult = 1.0
m3Mult = 1.0
m4Mult = 1.0

# distance threshold
distThresh = 12.0
distCutOff = 30.0

# speeds
speedDef = 200
leftSpeed = speedDef
rightSpeed = speedDef
turnTime = 1.0
defTime = 0.1
driveTime = defTime

def driveMotors(leftChnl = speedDef, rightChnl = speedDef, duration = defTime):
    # determine the speed of each motor by multiplying
    # the channel by the motors multiplier
    m1Speed = leftChnl * m1Mult
    m2Speed = leftChnl * m2Mult
    m3Speed = rightChnl * m3Mult
    m4Speed = rightChnl * m4Mult

    # set each motor speed. Since the speed can be a
    # negative number, we take the absolute value
    mot1.setSpeed(abs(int(m1Speed)))
    mot2.setSpeed(abs(int(m2Speed)))
    mot3.setSpeed(abs(int(m3Speed)))
    mot4.setSpeed(abs(int(m4Speed)))

    # run the motors. if the channel is negative, run
    # reverse. else run forward
    if(leftChnl < 0):
        mot1.run(amhat.BACKWARD)
        mot2.run(amhat.BACKWARD)
    else:
        mot1.run(amhat.FORWARD)
        mot2.run(amhat.FORWARD)

    if (rightChnl > 0):
        mot3.run(amhat.BACKWARD)
        mot4.run(amhat.BACKWARD)
    else:
        mot3.run(amhat.FORWARD)
        mot4.run(amhat.FORWARD)

    # wait for duration
    time.sleep(duration)

try:
    while 1:
        # read the serial port
        val = ser.readline().decode('utf=8')
        print val

        # parse the serial string
        parsed = val.split(',')
        parsed = [x.rstrip() for x in parsed]

        # only assign new values if there are
        # three or more available
        if(len(parsed)>2):
            distMid = float(parsed[0] + str(0))
            distLeft = float(parsed[1] + str(0))
            distRight = float(parsed[2] + str(0))

        # apply cutoff distance
        if(distMid > distCutOff):
            distMid = distCutOff
        if(distLeft > distCutOff):
            distLeft = distCutOff
        if(distRight > distCutOff):
            distRight = distCutOff

        # reset driveTime
        driveTime = defTime

        # if obstacle to left, steer right by increasing
        # leftSpeed and running rightSpeed negative defSpeed
        # if obstacle to right, steer to left by increasing
        # rightSpeed and running leftSpeed negative
        if(distLeft <= distThresh):
            leftSpeed = speedDef
            rightSpeed = -speedDef
        elif (distRight <= distThresh):
            leftSpeed = -speedDef
            rightSpeed = speedDef
        else:
            leftSpeed = speedDef
            rightSpeed = speedDef

        # if obstacle dead ahead, stop then turn toward most
        # open direction. if both directions open, turn random
        if(distMid <= distThresh):
            # stop
            leftSpeed = 0
            rightSpeed = 0
            driveMotors(leftSpeed, rightSpeed, 1)
            time.sleep(1)
            leftSpeed = -150
            rightSpeed = -150
            driveMotors(leftSpeed, rightSpeed, 1)
            # determine preferred direction. if distLeft >
            # distRight, turn left. if distRight > distLeft,
            # turn right. if equal, turn random
            dirPref = distRight - distLeft
            if(dirPref == 0):
                dirPref = random.random()
            if(dirPref < 0):
                leftSpeed = -speedDef
                rightSpeed = speedDef
            elif(dirPref > 0):
                leftSpeed = speedDef
                rightSpeed = -speedDef
            driveTime = turnTime

        # drive the motors
        driveMotors(leftSpeed, rightSpeed, driveTime)
        ser.flushInput()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    mot1.run(amhat.RELEASE)
    mot2.run(amhat.RELEASE)
    mot3.run(amhat.RELEASE)
    mot4.run(amhat.RELEASE)
```

Perhaps an indentation issue somewhere? I've been playing around with the code for a few hours and haven't really gotten anywhere. If any of you guys could help that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe whatever should be providing data via serial isn't providing it frequently enough for your program. I'd be tempted to just catch this error and try again (perhaps waiting a little first). So instead of

```
try:
    while 1:
        # read the serial port
        val = ser.readline().decode('utf=8')
        print val
```

do

```
from time import sleep
...
try:
    while 1:
        # read the serial port
        try:
            val = ser.readline().decode('utf=8')
            print val
        except SerialException:
            sleep(0.01)  # Maybe don't do this, or mess around with the interval
            continue
```

Comment: I implemented the try... except block without the sleep (sleep kept giving errors) and it stopped giving me errors altogether... problem is nothing is happening still. So we beat the errors but still nothing is moving.

Comment: You don't quite explicitly say what's on the other side of the serial, is it an Arduino? If so, you could try reducing the serial speed at both ends to see if that helps. And of course double check that you are using the same settings on one side of the serial connection as the other, and that your Arduino is actually sending stuff. Can you try running a serial terminal on the Pi to confirm you can communicate with the Arduino using your chosen settings?